# Check exist before insert

Tags: php

I have a script that checks if a record exists before inserting a new record into the database:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select post_url from vinanghinguyen_posts where post_url = '$final_url'")) < 1)
{
   //insert 
}
```

If `post_url` is already in the database then do not insert. I check in database. I have some `post_url` like `$final_url` but it still inserts normally. Why?

Comment: sorry, can't understand your question

Comment: need a script check data need insert in the database exists or not

Comment: Have you tried running this query on the command line?  Are you sure `final_url` is set properly?  Are you sure the right DB is selected?  Are you sure a DB connection has been made at all?

Answer (score 2):

Use "`== 0`" in replace of "`< 0`" in if condition. The total number of rows in database will never less than 0, it must be 0 or greater than 0. And one more thing never use **`=`** for check operator use **`==`**

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select post_url from vinanghinguyen_posts where post_url = '$final_url'")) == 0)
{
   //insert 
}
```

Comment: Please put the whole code with condition and insert query. Also var_dump the result that query is throwing

Answer (score 0):

just check true and false condition

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select post_url from vinanghinguyen_posts where post_url = '$final_url'")))
{
  //insert 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to enforce the uniqueness of `post_url` in your schema by [adding a unique key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX vinanghinguyen_posts_unique_url
ON vinanghinguyen_posts( post_url )
```

Now you can make the database do the work by telling it to ignore duplicate entries

```
//clean the data
$final_url = mysql_real_escape_string( $final_url );

mysql_query( "INSERT IGNORE INTO
              vinanghinguyen_posts
              VALUES
              ('$final_url')" );
```